# Differential equation for a vector : condition to be conservative

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume there is a vector $\mathbf{N}(t)$ of elements $N_i$ and of dimension $n$ and there are matrices $\mathbf{B}_i$ of dimension $n\times n$, and that :

$\begin{equation}\left\{ \begin{split}& \frac{dN_i(t)}{dt}=\mathbf{N}(t)^T\mathbf{B}_i\mathbf{N}(t) \\ & \frac{d(\sum_{i=0}^n N_i(t))}{dt}=0 \end{split} \right. \end{equation}$

Are there conditions on $\mathbf{B}_i$ and $\mathbf{N}(t=0)$ so that the conservation condition over $\sum_{i=0}^n N_i$ is realized ?

The second equation leads to $\mathbf{N}(t)^T(\sum_i \mathbf{B}_i)\mathbf{N}(t)=0$ with an obvious solution : $\sum_i \mathbf{B}_i=0$.

But can one say more things apart from this obvious solution ?

Comment: The first equation has a dimension mismatch.

Comment: Not unit, dimension. A $n \times 1$ vector can't multiply on the left of a $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Right ! I'm correcting that thx

Comment: This still makes no sense. Do you want $\frac{dN_i}{dt}=N^T B_i N$?